# Develop nucleotide sequence

Tags: r, regex, bioinformatics, dna-sequence

I would like to develop these expressions that are in this form:

```
a <- "[AGAT]5GAT[AGAT]7[AGAC]6AGAT"
```

I would like to convert the expression like this:

```
b <- "AGATAGATAGATAGATAGATGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGACAGACAGACAGACAGACAGACAGAT"
```

As you can see, the number after the hook means the number of times the pattern is found.

For the moment I use `sub(".*[*(.*?) *].*", "\\1", seq)` for select character between `[]` and `replicate(i, "my_string")` for replicate sequence between `[]` but I do not find how to make it work with my data.

I hope to be pretty clear.

Comment: Could you please your expected output.  If the letters inside the `[]` needs to be replicated, it looks different

Comment: Looks like it would have been much easier if you could get something like `a=[AGAT]5[GAT]1[AGAT]7[AGAC]6[AGAT]1` instead from the process that generates your expressions. This is a more consistent format.

Comment: @AntoniosK I totally agree with you but biologists have their logic ... but your solution is what we must understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
a<-"[AGAT]5GAT[AGAT]7[AGAC]6AGAT"

   list<-unlist(strsplit(unlist(strsplit(a,"\\]")),"\\["))

   number<-suppressWarnings(as.numeric(gsub("([0-9]+).*$", "\\1", list)))
   number[is.na(number)]<-1  
   seq<-gsub('[0-9]+', '', list)

   out<-paste(rep(seq[2:(length(seq))],number[c(3:length(number),2)]),collapse = '')

 b="AGATAGATAGATAGATAGATGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGACAGACAGACAGACAGACAGACAGAT"

out==b
[1] TRUE
```

The output is correct, but I don't know if is a general solution for every kind of data in input

Answer (score 3):

We use `gsub` to create 1s where there is no number before the `[` ('a1'), then extract the letters and numbers separately ('v1', 'v2'), do the replication with `strrep` and `paste` the substrings to a single string ('res')

```
library(stringr)
a1 <- gsub("(?<![0-9])\\[", "1[", a, perl = TRUE)
v1 <- str_extract_all(a1, '[A-Z]+')[[1]]
v2 <- str_extract_all(a1, "[0-9]+")[[1]]
res <- paste(strrep(v1, as.numeric(c(tail(v2, -1), v2[1]))), collapse='')
res
```

-output

```
#[1] "AGATAGATAGATAGATAGATGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGACAGACAGACAGACAGACAGACAGAT"
```

-checking with the 'b'

```
identical(res, b)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

A slightly more compact regex would be to change the first step

```
a1 <- gsub("(?<=[A-Z])(?=\\[)|(?<=[A-Z])$", "1", a, perl = TRUE)
v1 <- str_extract_all(a1, '[A-Z]+')[[1]]
v2 <- str_extract_all(a1, "[0-9]+")[[1]]
res1 <- paste(strrep(v1, as.numeric(v2)), collapse="")
identical(res1, b)
#[1] TRUE
```

#### data

```
a <- '[AGAT]5GAT[AGAT]7[AGAC]6AGAT'
b <- 'AGATAGATAGATAGATAGATGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGACAGACAGACAGACAGACAGACAGAT'
```

Comment: it does not give the correct output. GAT (second position) and AGAT (last position) are missing.

Comment: @DJack  I am replicating the letters inside the `[]`.  Which one do you want?  Is it inside or outside?

Comment: Thank you for your help, however it is not the right solution because the output is not good. The numbers between brackets must be repeated the number of times indicated by the number after the brackets. When there is no brackets then there is no repetition.

Comment: @yach It is confusing.  For example `[AGAT]5` it seems like AGAT is replicated 5 times, then then next `[AGAT]7` also replicated 7 ?

Comment: here is a more readable output : AGATAGATAGATAGATAGAT  GAT  AGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGATAGAT  AGACAGACAGACAGACAGACAGAC  AGAT

Comment: @akrun it does not work with all my data. This is not your fault, it comes sometimes from my data that vary for example there are times when we have hooks without number after. thanks for your help